# Play downloaded Video phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, video, download

how can play downloaded video by using phonegap new FileManager();  Plugin ?
in javascript using this

```
var a = new DirManager(); // Initialize a Folder manager
            a.create_r('assets/css',Log('complete/ m0101 img '));
            var b = new FileManager();
    b.onFileSystemSuccess('https://www.prices92.com/videos/2016/08/24/1472027345257d9-hd.mp4','cdvfile://localhost/persistent/resources/introHD.mp4');
```

and in HTML using this

```
<video   id="myVideo3" preload="none" poster="resources/videoposter.png" width="100%" controls>
                        <source   src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/assets/css/introHD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
```

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer to this question, not as a new question.

Comment: You don't see the answer box under the question here? Are you answer banned for providing bad answers?